# firebase.database is not a function why I am getting this error in react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting this error when I tried to fetch data from Firebase realtime database-

> AboutApp.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: *config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9*_.firebase.database is not a function
> at AboutApp.js:9:1

Is there anything wrong on my code?

Please check the database structure

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {View, Button, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import {firebase} from '../config';


const AboutApp = ({ navigation }) =>{
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
 const users = firebase.database().ref("first");
 users.on("value",datasnap=>{
    console.log(datasnap.val());
 });
 setUsers(users)

}, [])


    return (
       <View style={{ flex:1, marginTop: 100}}>
           <FlatList
           style={{height: '100%'}}
           data={users}
           numColumns={1}
           renderItem={({item}) => (
             <Pressable
         style={styles.container}>
         <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
             <Text>{item.name}</Text>
             <Text>{item.email}</Text>
             <Text>{item.phone}</Text>
             
         </View>
         
             </Pressable>
           )}
           />
            </View>
         );
         
         }
    export default AboutApp;
```

Please check the config file-

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBS93aTCkwMyEWU15HR5y454qZM_WTDXhAo",
  authDomain: "newawesome-18ee9.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "newawesome-18ee9",
  storageBucket: "newawesome-18ee9.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "441185679151",
  appId: "1:441187374121:web:ecf6de832274a4480b8610",
  measurementId: "G-R6NM36814P"
};

if (!firebase.apps.length){
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}
export {firebase};
```

Comment: Can you also share your "'../config'" file? You are probably using new Modular SDK but using syntax of old version.

Comment: Dharmaraj please check the config file above

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database) and not [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore). You are not importing the RTDB SDK. Try adding the following import:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'

import 'firebase/compat/database' // <-- Import RTDB SDK
```

Also, Firebase will be removing the "compat" SDK in future updates so it'll be best to upgrade your code to the new Modular SDK. Checkout the  [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for more information.